# How to resolve "keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)"

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

I am planning to use Java 11 instead of Java 8. I face this error when I use Java 11 as a base image. However, the Dockerfile runs fine, if I use the jdk8 base image. Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.repo1.aaa.com/ecap/base-images/centos-8-openjdk11:latest
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR .
COPY bbb-service/target/*.jar bbb-service.jar
COPY aaa-engine/target/*.jar aaa-engine.jar
COPY certs/* /tmp/cacerts/
COPY aaa-service-chart aaa-service-chart
#Cert Creation
RUN ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/keytool -noprompt -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -importcert -alias aaa-ca-full -file /tmp/cacerts/aaa_ca1_full_chain.pem
CMD ["java", "-jar", "aaa-engine.jar"]
```

Jenkins build logs:

```
---> Running in 851cd67765d4
[91mCertificate was added to keystore
[0mkeytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
The command '/bin/sh -c ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/keytool -noprompt -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -importcert -alias aaa-ca-full -file /tmp/cacerts/aaa_ca1_full_chain.pem' returned a non-zero code: 1
[Pipeline] echo
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: That seems like your base image isn't setting the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JDK11+ following should be the correct path. At least that's where I have my certs in my local installation.

```
${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts
```